# Keep selection history Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, drop-down-menu

In my homepage I have multiple dropdowns which limits the data to be viewed, exactly 5 dropdowns. What I have done is as the user selects some option the url becomes `www.mywebsite.com/selection1/XX` where `XX` is the selection number same for other dropdowns. URL may become like this `www.mywebsite.com/selection1/XX/selection2/XX/selection3/XX`.

What I want to do is to have the user redirected to his previous selection if it exists. So, I added a column to `user` model called `history_url` and using the `onunload` I use an ajax to submit the new url.

It is unsafe as the user may just put anything into his address bar and I then will have that saved on the `history_url`.

Can I for example validate the URL given by the AJAX and only store it if it's available from my website (I know that I can check if it matches a route but I am talking about if the user changes any of the `XX`, which is meant to be an ID, to anything else)?

Is there a better way of doing it? Is What I am doing right? Are there any gems that does that?

Comment: Is there some reason you want to save history in the database (maybe to record metrics)? I'd save a limited number of URLs to the session and add a "favorites" mechanism. You should also be building your URL history in your  model rather than grabbing it from the url field, which makes it impossible for your users to spoof URLs.

Comment: That's going to get massively messy in a hurry. If you're going down that road, maybe investigate [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) as it has a more robust client-side state tracking feature. Using the anchor tag here would help: `/#selection1=xx,selection2=xx` where you can define your own serialization.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I save it to redirect the user to the history url on his next visit to a bear `www.mywebsite.com`. Because it's 70% probability he will have the same selections and I also want to allow him to select different stuff.
Would you tell me more about what do you mean by the "favorites mechanism"?
@tadman It's too late to switch to Angular for me.